# Redirect user to specific url after submitting the edit account address form

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How can I redirect a user to a custom URL after he submits the edit address form? For example I want to redirect the user to his account (my-account) instead of my-account/edit-address.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Used `woocommerce_customer_save_address` action hook

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that but if I add an action to this hook which should redirect the user, nothing happens. User is still being redirected to my-account/edit-address.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add this code in you function.php file

```
function action_woocommerce_customer_save_address( $user_id, $load_address ) { 
       wp_safe_redirect(wc_get_page_permalink('myaccount')); 
       exit;
}; 
add_action( 'woocommerce_customer_save_address', 'action_woocommerce_customer_save_address', 99, 2 );
```